# python script to fetch users from a google domain

Tags: python, gdata

here's python script that is supposed to fetch users from a google domain... for some reasoni seem to get an authorization header error. Dont know what I am missing tried searching all over but no success.

below is the entire python script.

```
import gdata.apps.service
import gdata.apps.groups.service
from array import *
import simplejson as json

consumer_key = '*******'
consumer_secret = 'd#######Q' #check advanced / OAuth in you control panel
sig_method = gdata.auth.OAuthSignatureMethod.HMAC_SHA1

service = gdata.apps.service.AppsService(domain=consumer_key)
service.SetOAuthInputParameters(sig_method, consumer_key, consumer_secret=consumer_secret, two_legged_oauth=True)
words=""
myDict = {}


res = service.RetrieveAllUsers()
for entry in res.entry:
    #words.append(entry.login.user_name)
    #myDict[entry.login.user_name] = entry.login.user_name
 words+=str(entry.login.user_name)+","


print words
```

I get an error at retrieveallusers().